# Checking for object property or method with a piping function

Tags: javascript, object, properties, object-literal

Imagine this simple setup:

```
var obj = {

    // Extends the object by adding another property or method
    extend: function(key, obj){
        this[key] = obj;
    }

}
```

Now i can use this:

```
obj.extend('panelControl', {
   open: function(){},
   close: function(){}
});
```

To add the key `panelControl` to `obj` which works just fine.

In order to call the panel control functions in the above example, i would do this:

```
obj.panelControl.open();
```

Which works fine as long as `panelControl` actually exists / has been set. But if not, then i get an exception, of course.

Now my idea was to create a function that acts as a pipe:

```
var obj = {

    // Definition of extend function goes here

    // Used to safely access properties or methods with regard to availability
    pipe: function(key){
        if(typeof this[key] !== 'undefined')
           return this[key];
    }

}
```

So i would call:

```
obj.pipe('panelControl').open();
```

This works great as long as `panelControl` is there / has been set.

The problem is that when `panelControl` does has not been defined, `pipe()` gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined
```

But this is exactly what i was trying to avoid by doing:

```
if(typeof this[key] !== 'undefined') {}
```

I researched the matter and found some approaches, which basically are mimicking PHP's `isset()` functionality:

```
if(key in this) {}
```

Or:

```
if(this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {}
```

(The latter being unavailable in some versions of IE)

I applied all of them but still got the TypeError.

Obviously i misunderstand the behaviour of the condition i wrote. Perhaps my approach is flawed altogether. And perhaps there are much better ways to do what i am trying to achieve.

**How can i:**

Create a function just as i try to do with `pipe()` which passes a local property of the object it is called on, but only if it exists, and which cancels the method chain (i.e `obj.pipe('panelControl').open()` so that no exceptions or occur?

**?**

Note: if there is a better way to do this, one perhaps that does not even involve a method as i intended to implement with `pipe()` or just something simpler or more safe, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: When `panelControl` is not set, it should do nothing?

Comment: Correct, that would be best.